# Turn off TS4023 typescript error: external module "xyz" but cannot be named

Tags: typescript

```
//feature1.slice.ts

import { createGenericSlice } from '@me/data-rtk';

/* ***********************For Storing all the divisions data****************************** */
export const divisionDataSlice = createGenericSlice({
  name: 'divisiondata',
  initialState: { status: 'loading' },
} )({
  setDivisionData(state, { payload }) {
    state.data = payload;
  },
});


/**************------------------*******************************/


//@me/data-rtk File
interface GenericState<T> {
  data?: T;
  status: 'loading' | 'finished' | 'error';
}

type Obj = Record<string, any>;

export const createGenericSlice = <D extends Obj, T extends Obj>({
  name = '',
  initialState,
}: {
  name: string;
  initialState: GenericState<T>;
}) = {return //Reducers}
```

My above code is returning the following error. Is there a flag/config to turn off this type of errors.

```
Error during bundle: Error: feature1.slice.ts(4, 14): semantic error TS4023: Exported variable 'divisionDataSlice' has or is using name 'GenericState' from external module "rtk-slice" but cannot be named.
```

I had gone through tsConfig Possible options & tried, but did'nt work.

If there is no way to turn off this error, is there a way to fix this error from the code.

Comment: Enable `skipLibCheck` so TS doesn't check libraries you're using.

Comment: @vera. I see flag skipLibCheck  is already enabled, but still seeing this error

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bypass the error by setting type as any for the assignment.
export const divisionDataSlice**: any** = createGenericSlice({})

Since any opts-out of static typing, the compiler does not need to figure out the shape of divisionDataSlice.